Understanding TensorFlow GradientTape when there is recurrence
Following on from my previous question, I want to investigate what GradientTape does when a watched variable is used more than once in the calculation, in particular when a neuron has an input that comes from its own output.
I've created this minimal demonstration, which has one neuron with two inputs - one from outside, one from its own output. Its output is calculated twice.
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def one_training_step(X, y, loss_fn, activation_fn):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        out = tf.zeros((1,1))
        for _ in range(2):
            a = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[X, out])
            out = activation_fn(a @ w + b)
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_true=y, y_pred=out)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, [w, b])
    tf.print(f"Watched: {tape.watched_variables()}")
    tf.print(f"Grads: {grads}")

X = tf.constant([[1.0]], dtype=float, name='X')
y = tf.constant([[1.0]], dtype=float, name='y')
w = tf.Variable([[2.0], [3.0]], dtype=float, name='w')
b = tf.Variable([[4.0]], dtype=float, name='b')
activation_fn = tf.keras.activations.get('sigmoid')
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
one_training_step(X, y, loss_fn, activation_fn)

This prints the following:
Watched: (<tf.Variable 'w:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Variable 'b:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>)
Grads: [<tf.Tensor 'AddN_1:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'AddN_2:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32>]

This doesn't tell me anything about what is going on. I don't understand why the weight's gradient is now being recorded as an addition (rather than the multiplication when there was no recurrence).
What I really want to see is a list of all the recorded differentiable steps, so I can see if GradientTape is going to correctly apply them even in this case of recurrence.
